# how to remove sublime editor from git

Tags: git, sublimetext2

I added sublime to the default git editor. But I got error msg like this:

```
ubl -n -w: subl: command not found
error: There was a problem with the editor 'subl -n -w'.
```

I don't want to use sublime anymore, anyone knows how to remove sublime editor from git

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change your default editor (to vi for example) with:

`git config --global --add core.editor vi`

where `--global` means you are changing the settings globally. You can also change the settings locally (`--local`) in the current repository and using the system (`--system`).

You can see what your current config is with `git config -l`.

Edit: If you just want to remove the editor instead of adding a new one, use:

`git config --global --unset-all core.editor`

Comment: I still get `line 267: subl: command not found
Could not execute editor` even after removing the the editor